# Cannot connect Jenkins jlnp slaves to Centos 7 master installed using Docker jenkins/jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins, port, firewall, jenkins-agent

Jenkins Centos 7 master was installed from Docker [jenkins/jenkins](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/).

I cannot connect my old Windows 7, macOS, and Linux slaves to the master using jlnp.

Usually the Jenkins slave agent displays:

- "Trying protocol: JNLP4-connect"
- "Terminated"
- Repeat

Clues:

- Occasionally Windows7 "Jenkins slave agent" will display "Connected".
- However, the Jenkins master displays the node as **not connected**.

Installed Using:

```
sudo systemctl start docker
sudo docker pull jenkins/jenkins
sudo docker run --name jenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -u 1001 -v /home/jenkins/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=http --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Added Clues:

- This is my first time using a Docker install of jenkins.
- It is running a /home/jenkins/jenkins.
- I can find no useful clues in /jenkins/logs/slaves/
- I tied disabling Centos & firewall on both master and slave

  I am docker newbie.

  sudo docker logs -f jenkins

displayed a JNLP4 connect error saying root was not writable.

My issue sounds very similar to this:

[docker-slave never connects to master if User is defined in configuration #474](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-plugin/issues/474)

I changed to run the LTS version and now I can connect a slave:

```
sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

Comment: output of `sudo iptables -S` on your centos machine? Do this after shutting all containers and stopping docker service

Comment: Thank you Tarun.  I added both "docker ps" and iptables output to the question.

Comment: Have you customized the `/etc/docker/daemon.json`?

Comment: No. Do I need to customize `/etc/docker/daemon.json`?  I copied an "Error response from daemon..." above that occurs when I try to restart jenkins.  This did not occur the first time I launched it.

Comment: I am not sure why you are not seeing any rules of Docker in iptables?

Comment: I think I will delete container, jenkins home, and start again. This time I will try to get slaves going before I copy the jenkins config.xml and jenkins jobs folder.  **Maybe copying over config.xml was the problem?** The **config.xml** contains a setting for **slaveAgentPort 50648**

Comment: I started over from scratch and still cannot connect a slave to the master.
My issue sounds very similar to this: [docker-slave never connects to master if User is defined in configuration #474](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-plugin/issues/474) .  Basically you cannot specify the jenkins user in the **docker run** command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having issues I suggest as a starter to try run as privileged user. That is of course not a good secured practice, but at least it can assist you in finding the root cause. for more details see:https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities

```
docker run  --privileged=true  -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

I would do a better dive also on the network you expose on the docker run, i.e. --network=host. for more options see: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings

```
docker run  --network=host -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

will allow your jenkins docker to take over the network interface of the machine. Again, not a good practice but excellent for debugging purposes.